# Trying to install Ubuntu along with Windows 10 but grub file missing and the result from boot-repair made everything worse

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

recently, I’m trying to install Ubuntu and Windows 10. My mistake is install Ubuntu with Legacy mode.

After restarting my PC, grub  bootloader wasn’t show and I was trying to fix that by using command `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi` in window cmd then everything messed up. I can’t even boot into Windows anymore.

However, I didn’t give up otherwise tried to boot from Ubuntu live-usb and then using boot-repair with recommended settings now, it’s gone and beyond my ability. Ubuntu even unable to show Windows ntfs mounted partitions (checking with lsblk) but in fdisk all the Microsoft partitions still there.

So, I used the last option which is boot from Windows live usb but unfortunately, my pc unable to boot from this.

Any suggestion ? or I must give up and sat goodbye to my data T-T

Comment: UEFI & BIOS are not really compatible, You may have to switch UEFI settings to boot one or the other. Always best to have all systems in same boot mode. Lets see details, use ppa version with your Ubuntu  live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair  And boot Ubuntu live installer in UEFI boot mode, to show what is in UEFI.